# Temporarily resetting figure counters within a chapter

Tags: floats, numbering, counters

The code below works perfectly in an `article` (permitting me to put two captions in the same figure and have one of them called *Table*, picking up the table counter—there’s a sensible reason for doing this).  However, in a `chapter`, the code ceases to work:

- an extraneous “0.” follows the first caption
- an extraneous “1.” follows the table,
- the figure and table are labeled “Figure 1.1” and “Table 1.2”, rather than what I want: “Figure 1.1” and “Table 1.1”.

I guess I don’t understand how the `figure` and `table` counters work within a chapter.  How can I fix this?

[image]

(I also not that the code is incompatible with `pdfpages.sty`, but fine with `geometry.sty`, which is curious.)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}

\begin{figure}

\fbox{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}
\caption{Alphabet}
 \renewcommand{\figurename}{Table}
 \setcounter{figure}{\thetable}
\caption{Numerals}\medskip
\begin{tabular}{l}1\\23\\456\\7890\end{tabular}
 \renewcommand{\figurename}{Figure}
 \setcounter{figure}{\thefigure}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for a latex counter `\the....` is the *print form* not the value of the counter

```
 \setcounter{figure}{\thetable}
```

should be

```
 \setcounter{figure}{\value{table}}
```

Answer (score 4):

There's a much neater way:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{capt-of}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}

\begin{figure}

\fbox{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}
\caption{Alphabet}

\medskip

\captionof{table}{Numerals}
\medskip
\begin{tabular}{l}1\\23\\456\\7890\end{tabular}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Instead of `capt-of` you can use `caption`, that allows for many customizations of captions.

[image]

Note that with this method, the table and the figure captions will go to the right lists, should you typeset them. With your method, even if fixed for getting correct numbering, the `table` caption inside `figure` will go in the list of figures.

Comment: Thanks for this more general solution.  I'll look into `capt-of` (especially if the publisher I'm using usually prints lists of figures/tables).